# The [roll] tag is ambiguous

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, ambiguous-tags

There are currently 54 questions tagged with [roll](/questions/tagged/roll).

The usages of [roll](/questions/tagged/roll) include:

- Rolling dice - These should probably be only tagged [dice](/questions/tagged/dice) and not [dice](/questions/tagged/dice)[roll](/questions/tagged/roll).
- Yaw-Pitch-Roll
- iOS Camera Roll
- Misspelling 'Role'

Should this tag exist? If it should then there should be a definition in the tag wiki.

Comment: [tag:rick-roll]... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just killed it (go keyboard shortcuts!)

[image]

Comment: No fanfare? No drum roll? Pfft. ;)

Comment: I pretended to play a fanfare with a kazoo, and drummed my desk a bit.  Oh, and I gave you an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

I say we clean it up. Roll out. Before we start, we'll need to find out who is willing to help so be sure to take roll. It is sure to be a long job, and we'll be hungry, so you bring some fish and I'll bring a roll. Keep in mind that we will want to record the proceedings; perhaps you should roll tape.

I just remembered that there are toll roads between here and there, so be sure to bring a roll of quarters. Will we make it before dark? Dunno, it'll be a roll of the dice. Just make sure your car has good traction: I'd hate to see you roll it over.

By the way, what makes you think this word is ambiguous?

Comment: *rolls eyes*...

Comment: Don't try to stop me, I'm on a roll.

Comment: Shake, rattle, and ... burninate.